# Visual Studio 2013 with python tools not detecting apps in folder added in sys.path in intellisense

Tags: python, django, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have all my `django` apps in `apps/` module, which have an `__init__.py` file.
I have added this directory to `sys.path` in `settings.py` file and my code is running perfectly.

But the intellisense is not detecting the imports of apps and neither did I found any options to add python modules to intellisense.
So intellisense is showing me error like `unable to resolve <testapp>, intellisense may be missing in this module`.
How can I solve this error?

I am using pytools v2.1 beta.